# Cannot get ID of modalpopup in javascript

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have an update panel in my page. But modal popup is outside of that update panel.
When i try to get modal popup from javascript either using document.getElementById or $get or $find , it returns null, i.e. it cannot find that modal popup.

rough structural position of update panel and modal popup

```
<update panel>
</update panel>

<modal popup>
</modal popup>

<update panel>
</update panel>

<java script>
</java script>
```

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post actual- rather than pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0):

This work well for me.

```
 var ModalAction = '<%= ActionModalPopup.ClientID %>';
 $find(ModalAction).hide();
```

Comment: @Town Gasp! I really need a coffee!